# Is there a way to Set a Layout dynamically to a User Profile with APEX?

Tags: apex

I have created a custom page layout - now I need to set a user profile to this new layout. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can assign a standard page layout, for different record types, to the different profiles. That is standard configuration. What exactly do you want to do with Apex, and why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Apex code for this.

You should:
1) Create a new Record Type
2) Assign the Layout you made to that record type
3) Change the default Record Type for that object for that profile to the one you created.